# Why do animals yawn? What is the biology behind it?

Tags: human-physiology

We yawn whenever we are tired and body needs rest. Why does the mouth open wide and a large volume of oxygen is inhaled?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do we yawn?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/7011/why-do-we-yawn)

Comment: To some extent. Thank you for the link.